# Views slideshow is not being responsive in bootstrap theme

Tags: views, bootstrap-theme

I created 3 images. Each image size is 1300 x 600.

I created content type SLIDESHOW.

I added 3 contents to the SLIDESHOW.

I created a views slideshows.

[image]

I applied my css as below:

```
 .view-slideshowv .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame.views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section, .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row.views_slideshow_cycle_slide.views_slideshow_slide {
    width: 100% !important; 

}
.view-slideshowv .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row-item .field-content img {    
width: 100% !important;
    }
```

I placed the slideshow block in a region.
When I visit my page, width is always 100% width which takes the full width of the screen as expected but the height is not being responsive until I press refresh. It means when I visit the page in laptop/desktop, page loads fine. If I try to make the screen
smaller or larger, width is 100% of screen but the height is not being responsive until I hit refresh. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Use Flexslider .It is fully responsive slider.
https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider

Comment: Can I create a block with flex slider? Also, is there way I can fix the current issue that I am having with the views slideshows?

Comment: Yes you can create a view block.